# GDB: Is there some way to construct "Local" convenient variables?

Tags: gdb

I have an real-time OO program (nevertheless written in C) that I am trying to debug. I have an issue that some objects out of thousands get corrupted during a specific window of time, every now and then. I want to have one breakpoint at the start of the window, which automatically sets a watchpoint on a member variable, and then have that watchpoint removed at the end of the window by another breakpoint. The trouble is I need some way of tying a watchpoint number to a given object. If I could construct a convenience variable by some mechanism so that, for example, if `$var=28`, then `set $x${var}=watch -l foo` would be the equivalent of `set $x28=watch -l foo`. (which doesn't actually work) This would allow me to do this:

```
breakpoint obj_init+23
command
  $var = *obj
  $x${var} = watch -l foo
  continue
done

breakpoint obj_final
command
  $var = *obj
  delete $x${var}
  continue
done
```

So I don't (hopefully) overrun the number of available hardware watchpoints.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this without trying to write a python extension? (My python is very rusty.)

Comment: did you try valgrind? seems easier to setup and usually help in data corruption problems

Comment: I don't think it's possible without python. Also, I agree that you should try it with valgrind or sanitizers first.

Comment: valgrind was useless. Mostly because I'm running a gstreamer pipeline consisting of glib objects under python, and they ALL do strange things to memory handling. I was not able to get a useful run after a full day of trying, and yes, I've read the valgrind docs for each of the frameworks in question.

Comment: As for sanitizers I don't think they are (yet) enabled on my platform with gcc. I need to run these tests on CentOS and its years behind on compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GDB's [eval](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html#index-eval) command to set and use variables whose names are composed of the results of numeric or string expressions.

You can think of eval as doing a [printf](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html#index-printf) of its arguments and then executing the resulting string. `eval "set var $x%d = 1", 5` will run the command `set var $x5 = 1`.

The other piece of info you need is that the [watch](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#index-watch) command, as with all breakpoint commands, will set the convenience variable `$bpnum` to the breakpoint number.

```
break obj_init+23
commands
  set var $var = *obj
  watch -l foo
  eval "set var $x%d = $bpnum", $var
  continue
done

break obj_final
commands
  set var $var = *obj
  eval "delete $x%d", $var
  continue
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the 'eval' command!